# Struggling to position buttons in quiz game

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm very new to HTML, CSS and JS and I followed a tutorial to make a quiz. I wanted to add a score to my quiz so I attempted to start on the front end of the score count in order for it to be displayed. Because I couldn't manage to position the Question and the Score in the original div container, I put them into a separate container called "Question-container".

```
     <div class="container">
                <div id="question-container">
                <div id="question">Question</div>
                <div id="scorecount">Score</div>
                </div>
                  <div id="answer-buttons" class="btn-grid">
                    <button class="btn">Answer 1</button>
                    <button class="btn">Answer 2</button>
                    <button class="btn">Answer 3</button>
                    <button class="btn">Answer 4</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
        <div class="controls">
            <button id="start-btn" class="start-btn btn">Start</button>
            <button id="next-btn" class="next-btn btn hide">Next</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is the HTML I have used, however it now pushes the "Start" and "Next" button out of the container for some reason! [As seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TgN5.png)

It used to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5t6EI.png).

I hope some one can help me! I have a feeling it is to do with the javascript since I used the 'hide' function so when you click start it then displays the questions.

```
const startButton = document.getElementById('start-btn')
const nextButton = document.getElementById('next-btn')
const questionContainerElement = document.getElementById('question-container')
const questionElement = document.getElementById('question')
const answerButtonsElement = document.getElementById('answer-buttons')

let shuffledQuestions, currentQuestionIndex

startButton.addEventListener('click', startGame)
nextButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  currentQuestionIndex++
  setNextQuestion()
})

function startGame() {
  startButton.classList.add('hide')
  shuffledQuestions = questions.sort(() => Math.random() - .5)
  currentQuestionIndex = 0
  questionContainerElement.classList.remove('hide')
  setNextQuestion()
}
```

I hope someone can help!
Thanks,
Quest.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's because there's an unmatched closing div brace. (Next to the comment in the below snippet). It closes your `div.container` and therefore `div.controls` is outside of it and pushed out. Remove that line and it should go back as it was.

```html
<div class="container">
    <div id="question-container">
        <div id="question">Question</div>
        <div id="scorecount">Score</div>
    </div>
    <div id="answer-buttons" class="btn-grid">
        <button class="btn">Answer 1</button>
        <button class="btn">Answer 2</button>
        <button class="btn">Answer 3</button>
        <button class="btn">Answer 4</button>
    </div>
        </div>  <!-- what does this one close? -->
    <div class="controls">
        <button id="start-btn" class="start-btn btn">Start</button>
        <button id="next-btn" class="next-btn btn hide">Next</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Updated part about hiding and showing:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="question-and-answer-container">
        <div id="question-container"> ...
        <div id="answer-buttons" class="btn-grid"> ...
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
        <button id="start-btn" class="start-btn btn">Start</button>
        <button id="next-btn" class="next-btn btn hide">Next</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

...so that you can show / hide the relevant part. Hide `question-and-answer` and only show controls on start. Though, you'd probably both need a better name than question-and-answer, and a better structure.

---

Btw, don't get discouraged. This is programming. This thinking about structure. The fancy bits you might be hoping to achieve are nothing else than thinking about such structure upon thinking about such structure upon thinking about such structure... :) And if you get it wrong at the ground level, you can imagine how you only complicate the next level on top of it and the next level etc.

---

Another btw, I do realize you probably want to learn the basics first. And that's great. But do check out something like [pug](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html). The reason is that you (me, everyone) can only think about so many things at once. And programming is about managing complexity. Don't manage it by bashing your head against a missed div. Check out how more obvious the above looks in pug:

```
.container
    #question-container
        #question Question
        #scorecount Score
    #answer-buttons.btn-grid
        button.btn Answer 1
        button.btn Answer 2
        button.btn Answer 3
        button.btn Answer 4
    .controls
        button#start-btn.start-btn.btn Start
        button#next-btn.next-btn.btn.hide Next
```

`button.foo Text` is the same as `<button class='foo'>Text</button>`
No need to write div.container (it's just .container), and no need to close div, it's closed by indentation. # are ids, . are classes.

Now, don't get hung up on pug and what is npm install. But do get hung up on tooling, or in other words, how to simplify :)

Cheers and best of luck

Comment: After remove the </div> it displays the start button at the bottom of the container instead of hiding the questions and being centered https://i.imgur.com/qGOWDQk.png . In addition I do not see the next button when I click "Start" https://i.imgur.com/rKwOs3V.png  . Thanks for your help!

Comment: Oh then you probably don't want the controls inside the group container, but need another container. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If we indent your code correctly:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="question-container">
        <div id="question">Question</div>
        <div id="scorecount">Score</div>
    </div>
    <div id="answer-buttons" class="btn-grid">
        <button class="btn">Answer 1</button>
        <button class="btn">Answer 2</button>
        <button class="btn">Answer 3</button>
        <button class="btn">Answer 4</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="controls">
    <button id="start-btn" class="start-btn btn">Start</button>
    <button id="next-btn" class="next-btn btn hide">Next</button>
</div>
</div>
```

You can see that your `controls` div is outside your `container`, because of an extra closing `</div>` tag. Removing it should fix your issue.

Comment: After remove the </div> it displays the start button at the bottom of the container instead of hiding the questions and being centered https://i.imgur.com/qGOWDQk.png . In addition I do not see the next button when I click "Start" https://i.imgur.com/rKwOs3V.png  . Thanks for your help!